# The Context was not cast into Activity for latest Xamarin Project

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have created a new simple Dot Net project with a separate UI and ViewModel project for Android. I have used a simple Xamarin.Android EditText control to rendered in Forms control. In some scenarios, I will handle the keyboard manually. So I have used the below codes to handle the keyboard. But the Context was not cast to Activity. The specified case was not found exception has occurred.

Native Code:

```
public class Native_View : EditText
{
    public Native_View(Context context) : base(context)
    {
        OnLoading(context);
    }

    public Native_View(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs):base(context,attrs)
    {
        OnLoading(context);
    }

    public Native_View(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs, int defStyle):base(context,attrs,defStyle)
    {
        OnLoading(context);
    }

    private void OnLoading(Context con)
    {
        this.Text = "NativeControl";
    }

    protected override void OnFocusChanged(bool gainFocus, FocusSearchDirection direction, Rect previouslyFocusedRect)
    {
        base.OnFocusChanged(gainFocus, direction, previouslyFocusedRect);

        Window window = ((Activity)this.Context).Window;
        InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager)((Activity)this.Context).GetSystemService(Context.InputMethodService);

        if (window != null)
        {
            window.SetSoftInputMode(SoftInput.StateHidden);
            mgr.HideSoftInputFromWindow(this.WindowToken, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Forms PCL code:

```
public class FormsView : View
{
    public FormsView()
    {
    }
}
```

Forms Renderer code:

```
public class SourceForms_Renderer : ViewRenderer<Source_PCL.FormsView, Native>
{
    Native nativeView;

    public SourceForms_Renderer()
    {

    }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Source_PCL.FormsView> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (e.NewElement != null)
        {
            nativeView = new Native(Forms.Context);

            SetNativeControl(nativeView);           
        }
    }
}
```

Sample code:

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        <simpleFormsControl:FormsView />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Full sample link: https//www.c-sharpcorner.com/forums/uploadfile/392f47/07062018020515AM/SampleWithSource.zip

Please help me to use the keypad for explicitly.

Thanks